# Progress for zpool import -fFX

Tags: linux, debian, raid, zfs, data-recovery

I'm running zpool import -fFX on a 8x4TB striped, mirrored (raid10) pool. The documentation states the extreme rewind import (import -X) performs a full traversal of all blocks in the pool for verification. I'm also monitoring the disk data reads with iostat, and it shows 5.3TB total reads per disk at the moment. Is there any method to find out the percentage of the recovery process, I thought it should finish when it reach 4TB.

====== EDIT:

After 70 hours and 12.5tb/disk data read the zpool import -fFX  command restored everything (15TB) back. The pool is ONLINE and coherent. The per disk read speed were fluctuating between 1-130mb/s during the restore averaging arount 50mb/s.

Comment: Can you provide additional info on why you run import with -fFX? Metadata corruption?